# Linuxt mint debian printer uri

Tags: linux, printer, cups, linux-mint

I'm setting up a local printer in Linux Mint Debian using cups utility.  I'm just don't know what to put for the uri of printer? Where can I find the uri?

Answer (score 0):

should be something like

ipp://localhost:631/printers/printername.
socket://localhost:9100
... ect

depended on which protocol you use.

you can use lpadmin to add printer, check the device-uri